# rendering issue when resizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and I use the standard bootstrap classes to create a menu. I've restyled it so that the color is set to white with a purple backcolor. All is fine when the page is initially loaded. As I reduce the screen width with the mouse, my menu starts to collapse down as expected, but the menuappears to disappear. If I stop reducing the screen size and I then move my mouse over where the menu should be at that point it comes back into view. So the action is working, the menu isn't keeping it's color scheme whilst being moved. Have a missed a trick somewhere?

I get the same issue if I size my screen to e 767 such that my 'hamburger' button appears for the menu. I click the hamburger and nothing seems to display until I move my mouse over the left of the screen where the menu is.

Comment: don't know why this has been down voted. Would be more helpful if the downvoters told me what they don't like about my question

Answer (score 1):

When you resize you viewport size with your mouse, the end result is not always correctly shown because of the javaScript working on that resize.

Try to use only the specific window sizes given: Ipad Pro, Ipad, etc. After selecting use a CTRL + F5 or CTRL + SHIFT + R for a hard refresh, and afterwards tell me if the problem persists.

Also, check the built-in styles from bootstrap, it may change when you are on a tablet or mobile device.

Comment: I set my window such that my 'hamburger' menu comes into view. At that point I did a 'hard' refresh of the browser. I then pressed my hamburger button. The menu still didn't render on the left until I moved my mouse over that area which then brought everything back as expected. This is happening consistently not intermittent

Comment: This may be an issue regarding bootstrap. Try again in incognito mode to see if this could be a cache problem.

Comment: Also, where are you bootstrap libraries located?

Comment: I'm using the cdn's for bootstrap. both the js and css from maxcdn

Comment: Make sure you:

Copy-paste the stylesheet <link> into your <head> before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

Place the following <script>s near the end of your pages, right before the closing </body> tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins. 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+96

Comment: I tried incognito it made no difference. My load sequence in the header is : jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.css, font-awesome.min.css, mystyles.css

Comment: Your css stylesheets should be placed in the <head> section and the <script> tags at the end of your body tag, so they render correctly.

Comment: I notice your link is for 4.1.3 I'm using 3.3.7

Comment: you can change that manually, I just copy pasted the link for bootstrap documentation. insert your correct version.

Comment: I moved the script references from the head section to outside end of my body tag. This still made no difference after doing a hard refresh

Comment: you mean inside end right? Like this: <body> random HTML   <script>bootstrap js</script> </body> (not outside, right?)

Comment: I'm not referencing popper. Is there a cdn for this anywhere

Comment: Yes to where my script files are

Comment: can you offer a link so I can see the issue? This may also be a css problem, you are saying that the element is only showing after you hover over it. Check if the class has some opacity:0; set by default or something that is hiding it, and on hover makes it appear.

Comment: Here is the documentation for how to get started: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I've added a link to the popper cdn found on github. this has made no difference. Not really got a link as it's only in development at the moment. I've even removed all my custom script to see if that might be causing the issue. Still no luck. I don't have any opacity. But the first item on the menu, I set display none and visibility hidden as this isn't required on smaller devices

Comment: try removing the code you specified earlier, remove the hidden and display none, and see if the initial problem persists.

Comment: It still persists if I remove these 2 so that the first menu item still appears. This is the pattern that I get. Hard reload the page. press hamburger, just a vertical scroll bar shows for the menu. I can keep toggling the hamburger and the vertical scroll bar will toggle correctly no menu items render. The first time I mouse over the menu to bring the items into view, I can toggle the hamburger until my hearts content and the menu will toggle correctly

Comment: You can try copy pasting the html structure in a code snippet here : https://codepen.io/ and you can put there the bootstrap cdn's too. If it works there, it is not a bootstrap related problem. If not, you can provide me the link and I can investigate it easier.

Comment: Ok, I've never used codepen. I've just created an account and am trying to create a new project but not much luck. I'll get back to you when I've got something in there

Comment: It is fairly easy to use. Access: https://codepen.io/pen and input your html on the left (dont forget to put head tag with bootstrap css link and a body tag in which you will create your html content and at the end put the script tags), in the middle the css and no js needed for your code.

Comment: if I go to that view it will not let me type anything in any of the windows (html, js or css)....Ah doesn't work in i.e. only chrome

Comment: Hmmm.....that's interesting. I literally just cut and pasted all my code into the various windows. When I move the windows width such that my hamburger menu comes into view, the menu renders correctly. but when I do it for real in either i.e. or chrome. I get the strange behaviour

Comment: Yes, I'm fighting with that at the moment, but thought I'd try and tackle one issue at a time, I'd already done most of this when the requirement changed for me to place the search button on the top for smaller screens as opposed to in the menu itself.

Answer (score 0):

codepen.io/bilpor/pen/gjRQgj

So after seeing the codepen, this is the desktop result.
[image]
This is the menu before I hover over it.

[image]

And this is the image after I hover over elements.

Regarding your issue, use you javascript code to run only on desktop.

```html
 $(document).ready(function () {
    if (screen.width < 1024) {
        // your code that affect navbar here
    }
    
    else {
        alert(Error!);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, the view is correct at the moment. the 3 end options are that colour because they are empty links at the moment.